# How to group by column a and sum column b and c in a php array

Tags: php, array

I got the following array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [kanel] => 5
        [peber] => 0
        [shipping] => A
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [kanel] => 25
        [peber] => 0
        [shipping] => A
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [kanel] => 25
        [peber] => 0
        [shipping] => C
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [kanel] => 5
        [peber] => 0
        [shipping] => B
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [kanel] => 5
        [peber] => 0
        [shipping] => C
    )
```

I want to print the following:

> A Kanel: 30 Peber: 0
>
> B Kanel: 5 Peber: 0
>
> C Kanel: 30 Peber: 0

Literally grouping on `shipping`, sum on `kanel` and sum on `peber` as well.
I can find a lot on how to do it with one column, but it doesn't do the trick. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group and sum the values in your array by the shipping field, you can use a loop and a temporary associative array to store the intermediate results. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
  $shipping = $item['shipping'];
  if (!isset($result[$shipping])) {
    $result[$shipping] = array(
      'kanel' => 0,
      'peber' => 0,
    );
  }
  $result[$shipping]['kanel'] += $item['kanel'];
  $result[$shipping]['peber'] += $item['peber'];
}

// Print the results
foreach ($result as $shipping => $values) {
  echo $shipping . ' Kanel: ' . $values['kanel'] . ' Peber: ' . $values['peber'] . "\n";
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
A Kanel: 30 Peber: 0
B Kanel: 5 Peber: 0
C Kanel: 30 Peber: 0
```

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick flawless!